# Microsoft App Center add external package

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

How I do add packages sources in my project?

In my Visual Studio, i go to tools -> options -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Sources.

And add the package information that in this case is not in Nuget. Now in the App Center I did not find this information and with this my project does not compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [NuGet.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/faq#how-to-restore-a-private-nuget-feed) file as described in the docs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget" value="https://api.nuget.org/v2/index.json" />
    <add key="MyGet" value="https://www.myget.org/F/MyUsername/api/v2/index.json" />
    <add key="MyAuthNuget" value="https://nuget.example.com/v2/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <MyAuthNuget>
      <add key="Username" value="$USER_VARIABLE" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="$PASSWORD_VARIABLE" />
    </MyAuthNuget>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will also help somebody. For me the above solution haven't worked. So what I've discovered - always check if official source of packages is same as in your config. For now nuget source have changed to version 3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <activePackageSource>
        <add key="NuGet official package source" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```